# Show that $G_4(i)\neq 0$, and $G_6(\rho)\neq 0$, $\rho=e^{2\pi i /3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

Let $G_k$ denote the Eisenstein series of weight $k$. I know that $G_k(i)=0$ if $k \not\equiv 0 \ (mod \  4)$ and $G_k(\rho)=0$ if $k \not\equiv 0 \ (mod \  6)$. However, I want to know how to show, that $G_4(i)\neq0$ and $G_6(\rho)\neq0$, without using the $\frac{k}{12}$-formula.

Comment: I don't understand the question in detail, but I remember reading this, which might be of interest : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301073/direct-proof-of-the-non-zeroness-of-an-eisenstein-series

Comment: @patrick da silva yes that helped me. However, I thought, that one can only use the fourierseries for a sufficient big imaginary part.

Comment: Is your question completely answered by my link?

Comment: Partwise, but I found the solution

Comment: You should consider writing it down on this website for sake of completeness. If you had this question, perhaps other people did too.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Will do it soon, when I Come home.

Comment: I'd be interested in reading your solution :)

Comment: For the answer I was allowed to use that $\Delta\neq0$ for every $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$. Then one can easily show that $G_4(\rho)=0$ and $G_6(i)=0$. Since $\Delta$ is the product of $G_4$, $G_6$ and a constant. The claim follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a direct proof that $G_4(i) \neq 0$ that uses only the series.

The point is simply to estimate the tail $|a|,|b| \geq N$  and then calculate the first few terms for $|a|,|b| < N$.  In fact, using very simply bounds we can take $N=2$.

First note that $|a|+|b| \leq \sqrt{3}|a+bi|$ which follows from
$$ 2|a||b| \leq 2 (a^2+b^2) \implies a^2+b^2 + 2|a||b| \leq 3(a^2+b^2) \implies (|a|+|b|)^2 \leq 3(a^2+b^2). $$

This with integral comparison, easily gives  \begin{align*} \left|\sum_{|a|,|b| \geq N} \frac{1}{(a+bi)^4} \right| &\leq \sum_{|a|,|b| \geq N} \frac{1}{|a+bi|^4} \\\\ &\leq \sqrt{3}^4 \sum_{|a|,|b| \geq N} \frac{1}{(|a|+|b|)^4} \\\\ &= 9 \cdot 4 \sum_{a,b \geq N} \frac{1}{(a+b)^4} \\\\ &= 36 \sum_{a \geq N} \sum_{b \geq N} \frac{1}{(a+b)^4} \\\\ &= 36 \sum_{a \geq N} \sum_{b \geq N+a} \frac{1}{b^4} \\\\ &\leq 36 \sum_{a \geq N} \int_{N+a-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4}dx \\\\&= 12 \sum_{a \geq N} \frac{1}{(N+a-1)^3} \\\\&= 12 \sum_{a \geq 2N-1} \frac{1}{a^3} \\\\ &\leq 12 \int_{2N-2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^3} dx  \\\\ &= \frac{12}{(2N-2)^2} \\\\ &= \frac{3}{(N-1)^2}.  \end{align*}

Thus, when $N=2$, the tail is bounded by $\Large{\color{red}{3}}$.

Now, since conjugation permutes $\mathbb{Z} + i\mathbb{Z}$, we know that $G_4(i)$ is real.  Thus, we need only worry about the real part of the sum.  We have $$\text{Re} \left(\sum_{\substack{|a|,|b| < N \\ (a,b) \neq (0,0) }} \frac{1}{(a+bi)^4} \right) = \sum_{\substack{|a|,|b| < N \\ (a,b) \neq (0,0) }} \frac{a^4+b^4-6a^2b^2}{(a^2+b^2)^4}.$$  With $N=2$, a very short calculation gives $\Large{\color{red}{5}}$, a positive number.  Note that there is no way that the tail will make it negative.  Done.

Comment: This was also exercise 1 in section 6 chapter 1 of Koblitz' "Intro to Elliptic Curves and Modular Forms," and I believe the solution he had in mind was probably the one you mentioned in the comments, relating to the non-vanishing of the discriminant.  Since modular forms haven't been introduced prior Koblitz' $\S 1.6$, the non-vanishing ultimately depends on properties of the Weierstrass $\wp$-function.