# How to prove that $E_6(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})\ne 0$ where $E_6$ is the Eisenstein series of weight 6?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, modular-forms, modular-function

The fact that $E_6(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})\ne 0$ is considered to be obvious in some proofs of the facts about the Eisenstein series that I read, but I can't see it myself.

Please, help me to make it clear.

Comment: Would it just be a matter of computing the first few terms explicitly and putting bounds on the rest?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044686/show-that-g-4i-neq-0-and-g-6-rho-neq-0-rho-e2-pi-i-3?rq=1